# How do you get php to receive information from an html text box?

Tags: php, html, textbox

I'm trying to have an array display information inputted from a PHP-created HTML form. I'm trying to get the entire code on to one PHP file. So far, I have:

```
<body>
            <form action="hello.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Number" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="go()" />
            </form>
        </body>
```

The above code is generated using "echo" in PHP (not shown).

Then for the rest of the PHP, I have:

```
function go() {

            $variable = "input";
```

That is just the beginning of my code. The rest is unimportant. I know the $variable = "input"; part is wrong, but how do I get numbers to transfer over from inputted HTML to PHP? Thanks a lot!

Comment: use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) manual

Comment: U cant use php like JavaScript php runs server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a POST request you're going to want to refer to the `$_POST` superglobal. This variable is an array filled with any information sent by a POST request.

Since you want to get the value from "input" you would call the the `$_POST` variable using the key of "input"

```
function go() {
    $variable = $_POST['input'];
    // whatever else you want to do in your function
}
```

Since `$_POST` is a superglobal it is global in every scope.

You don't need to include the onclick event for your submit button, unless you wanted to call a JavaScript event with it. But the mapping of the JavaScript function go() and the PHP function go() have ZERO correlation between the two.

Comment: Hm. I know that there is a difference between single and double quotes in PHP. Why does it matter here?

Comment: I know $_REQUEST will work as well, but I'm told it's not good practice to use it. Not sure why though

Comment: It doesn't matter, there is the slightest, if not any, performance change. It's a personal preference to use single quotes when indexing an array.

Comment: Ortund, using `$_REQUEST` will envelope both POST and GET requests into one array. So you couldn't pass a value in the URI with `?id=` and have a form element submitted on a post request with the `name="id"`

Comment: Also, on a side note, is it possible to get html buttons to activate PHP functions? I don't need code, I just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: Well, in a sense yes, but you would be using an AJAX call if you didn't want to reload the page. If you didn't care about the page reloading you can use a simple if statement that would check to see if the POST request exists, then call a PHP function inside that if block.